# How to structure a Method in C# to get the logged in UserName, query Active Directory and return the user's full name

Tags: c#, vb.net, methods

I want to learn to make and use Methods in C#.

I know how to get the User Name of the currently logged in Windows user.  And I know how to query Active Directory to get their full name.  But, I'd like to make a reusable Method that I can put into other web applications as needed.

Would someone show me how that should or might be structured?

I've only done it this way, in VB.Net, and I may have a version of this in C# somewhere:

```
Protected Sub PopulateReviewerDDL()
    'Currently logged in user:  
    iUserName = Right(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"), (Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER").Length - 6)) 'Remove Domain name and backslash.

    Dim DBConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim DBCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECTADISNames", DBConn)
    DBCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Try
        DBConn.Open()
        DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@LogonName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iUserName

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = DBCmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        varLastName = dr("LastName").ToString
        varFirstName = dr("FirstName").ToString
        dr.Close()
        ReviewerName = varFirstName & " " & varLastName
        lblUserName.Text = ReviewerName

        If Not ddlReviewerName.Items.FindByText(ReviewerName) Is Nothing Then
            ddlReviewerName.Text = ReviewerName
        Else
            Response.Redirect("NoAccess.htm", False)
        End If

    Catch exp As Exception
        Response.Write(exp.Message)
    End Try
    'Close Database connection 
    DBCmd.Dispose()
    DBConn.Close()
    DBConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
protected string ClearDomain(string sItem)
{
    int sLoc = (sItem.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
    string sOutPut;
    sOutPut = sItem.Substring(sLoc);
    return sOutPut;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string usr;
    usr = ClearDomain(User.Identity.Name.ToString());
    string dpt;
    dpt = "";

    SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand DBCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECTADISNames", DBConn);
    DBCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
        DBConn.Open();
        DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@LogonName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usr;

        SqlDataReader dr = DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        // ContactPerson.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + dr["LastName"].ToString();
        // Notes.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();  // usr.ToString() + "@careersourcebroward.com"; // "Note: Your department is " + dr["Department"].ToString();

        email01.SelectedValue = dr["Email"].ToString();  // usr.ToString() + "@careersourcebroward.com";

        //if (!IsPostBack)
        //{
        //    Department.Text = dr["Department"].ToString();
        //}
        dpt = dr["Department"].ToString();

        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    DBCmd.Dispose();
    DBConn.Close();
    DBConn = null;

    // ############################################################################################  START ACCESS  #####################################
    //  Add and edit access list.  deptAccess is department access only.  allAccess is all access.  Add: IValentin |  Use same case as in Active Directory
    string[] deptAccess = {
    "mbateman",
    "rmoffett",
    "CCondon",
    "rpickett",
    "JLloyd",
    "rdaniels",
    "LKing",
    "SBreslin",
    "BCevieux",
    "bcharles",
    "TWeaver",
    "SGonzalez",
    "VSaget",
    "pchernofsky",
    "KRedford",
    "VSpellsAnderson",
    "jconnelly"
};
    string[] allAccess = {
    "MCJ",
    "chylton",
    "ykobrin",
    "CAzor",
    "mklincewicz",
    "mmagill",
    "tash",
    "dmegnin",
    "dhmegnin",
    "GValme",
    "gvalme",
    "mwatson",
    "lelmore",
    "IValentin",
    "TThomas",
    "AWiner",
    "PScott",
    "KKangal",
    "CCarcillo",
    "KHartzog",
    "CJohnson"

    };
    int pos01 = Array.IndexOf(deptAccess, usr);
    int pos02 = Array.IndexOf(allAccess, usr);

    if (pos01 > -1 && dpt == Department.SelectedItem.ToString() || pos02 > -1)  // (AND Department = usr's department)  (OR usr in master list for all access)  (use position numbers in the array and ElseIf like the color codes for accesses?)
    {
        //this.GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
        this.GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        Submit.Visible = true;
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //this.GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false;  //This adds a new "generated" column and throws off the column index counts.
        this.GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        Submit.Visible = false;
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
    // ############################################################################################  END ACCESS  #####################################
    /*
     * 
     * The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you miss...
     * May 26, 2008 01:30 PM
     * Hi,
     * I hope that you fixed the problem, just in case you did not add this line into web config where other assembly's are
     * <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
     * */
    Label1.Text = "Note: " + usr.ToString() + ", " + pos01.ToString() + ", " + pos02.ToString() + ", " + dpt;
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call InsertNewRecord
    InsertNewRecord();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Active.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to write that in C#?  We can help you get your solution working.

Comment: You've posted some code that appears to attempt what you want to do. What about it isn't working? Did you get an exception?

Comment: Mason, the issue may just be my lack of understand of just what a "method" is.  That code works fine.  LOL

Comment: Amy, I'll find a version of it in C# that I've used.  I'm pretty sure I've done it in C# at least once.  I started with VB and am still learning C# (Was still learning VB when I decided to switch.)

Comment: I couldn't find a C# version of the same little routine,  This is the whole default class of a web application I did to track contracts, that just happens to also use the "SELECTADISName" stored procedure to get names from Active Directory.  This is probably not very helpful and I apologize for for posting this long bit of code, but I thought it might show some of my poor coding.  I'm afraid I'm self taught and have no peers to review my code.  I'm sure I have some horrible practices.  Anyway, please give any criticisms, constructive or otherwise.  (I placed it in my original question)

Comment: It was too long....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code into methods or classes (whatever fits best) with the required  arguments. here is your modified version in C# :

```
 // ConnectionString make it globle access inside this class
    private string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString;

    protected void PopulateReviewerDDL()
    {
        // Currently logged in user:  
        var iUserName = GetCurrentUser();

        try
        {
            var reviewerName = GetReviewerName(iUserName, ConnectionString);

            if(reviewerName != null)
            {
                lblUserName.Text = reviewerName;

                if (!ddlReviewerName.Items.FindByText(reviewerName) == null)
                    ddlReviewerName.Text = reviewerName;
                else
                    Response.Redirect("NoAccess.htm", false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected string GetCurrentUser()
    {
        return Right(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"), (Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER").Length - 6));
    }

    protected string GetReviewerName(string username, string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Username or ConnectionString is Empty");

        string fullName = null;

        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECTADISNames", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.Add("@LogonName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        fullName = reader["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) // we need to catch sql errors only 
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        return fullName;
    }
```

Comment: Okay.  I see.  I need to read some more on structuring methods that return a value.  iSR5, that helps a lot by giving me something I'm familiar with to compare with the examples that are sometimes pretty confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "move your code into methods or classes" though.  You'd be fully justified by asking me "how long have you been programming?  A week?"  LOL

Comment: @DavidMegnin, what I meant, use your judgement to decide by examine your code, see which part can be reused, that you can take it apart and improve it for your code flexibility. For instance, if you see line that is redundant, then you can move it outside and make it accessible to other functions that already share it, just like the ConnectionString, I made it accessible on class level, so any method requires it can access it, no need to rewrite it again. You should read about code reuse concepts, it's worth reading.

Comment: I see.  Thank you, iSR5 for clarifying that.  I really appreciate it.